# Uploaded WebM video to YouTube, plays as MP4 in HTML5 mode

Tags: youtube

I uploaded a video encoded with WebM/VP8 codec (I am 100% sure, I used the WebM SDK example).
The video plays fine, but even in HTML5 mode it is an MP4 video instead of WebM. Other videos play as WebM for me. I tried in Chrome and Firefox (Firefox still uses the Flash player but Chrome plays it natively it seems). The problem is that in the html source only the mp4 video link is present.

The video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbF8GZDZ19s&html5=True (it is a research project for a class)

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is actually it just takes some time for YouTube to encode the video into WebM. It seems to start with flv and mp4 first.
It took about 1 day for that video to encode to WebM, works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing your video as WEBM in Chrome.  I'm using:

```
<iframe width="560" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/tbF8GZDZ19s" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I don't see anything that looks like an "mp4" in the HTML source or the DOM elements.  I just see the very cryptic URL for the video element's "src" parameter.  Though its only inserted once the video starts playing.

[image: Chrome cropped screenshot]

Comment: thanks for your reply. it turns out you just need to wait some time before the webm encoded version becomes available.